# Censoring comments

Tags: discussion, comments, policy

I believe comments which help people to go against the Torah by providing links to websites which teach you how to do so should be censored. Such links are, form a Torah point of view, comparable to links to sites teaching you how to make bombs to blow up people.

Comment: as far as lifnaai iver is concerned which is what I am talking about there is no different which avaira

Comment: @shulem, interesting point. I wonder if that's true halachically. Maybe I'll ask on-site.

Comment: Not [yet] making an argument either way, but looking for precedents. Here's one: The [AishDas](http://www.aishdas.org) Society, which openly promotes Torah-observance, maintains email discussion lists with [rules](http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/agree.shtml) and, apparently, a designated posek. These rules include one (#8) about censorship of links, and the categories of censorable links listed there does not include the one under consideration here.

Comment: Answers should address who decides and by what rules.  Is a link to a blog that, 17 entries back, mentions going to a movie on Shabbat censorable, for example?  If not, where's the line between that and a how-to manual for murder?

Comment: Is this about censoring comments or about censoring links?

Comment: ^^ or is this about censoring the contents of answers and questions, too?

Answer (score 3):

I think Mi Yodeya should not censor anything beyond off-topic, spam, and hate-baiting.

Why:

1. It's an implementation nightmare

   - It would be logistically difficult to enforce this - especially since change history is preserved.
   - ***ANY*** page that is linked to offsite is liable to be edited (or set up as a redirect to pornography).  Do we need to constantly monitor all links? And how would we put links back once the offending content is removed? That is a burden no one here wants.
2. It's a bureaucratic nightmare

   - Who makes these decisions? We don't have a posek, and I'm sure we can't all agree on who that would be.
   - Who decides who makes the decisions?  As a democratic community, we'd presumably have elections for this like everything else, but anyone with that power would be accused of abusing it.
   - What is the process for deciding to censor?  Is it committee? Are these open to the public?
3. It's unnecessary

   - There are already warnings throughout not to rely on anything here for halakhic advice.
   - We consider all people here to be adults capable of making their own decisions. This means they are responsible for their own actions.
   - Anything that is not worthwhile is already shut out in our current processes.  (Anything blatantly offensive or off-topic should be removed.)
4. It's a bad practice for this site

   - *Ezeh hu chacham?* - If we can learn some actual Torah from a site with instructions to build a bomb, or a site with an argument for not keeping the second day of Shavuot in galut, all the better.
   - This policy completely discourages newcomers from joining because they may be censored in a process they don't understand.
   - Having this policy creates more arguments and angry chat discussions than our current *laissez-faire* policy
   - It may be against StackExchange policy
   - Our site's target audience specifically includes "anyone interested in learning more".  This includes non-Jews.  A valid question may include links to sites that are specifically *avodah zarah* (e.g., "How does Judaism feel about neo-Baalism? Here are some differences between archaeo-Baalism and neo-Baalism...").  We should allow this sort of question and the website may be useful to flesh out the question.

Comment: Great. Now we all are going to go read about neo-Baalism. See, we don't even need links to have everyone reading about Avoda Zara!

Comment: We talked (briefly) about Achav in a class tonight, but we didn't actually read the details of archaeo-baalism.  Whew!